# How to add multiple items to apopup menu in java?

Tags: java, database, popup

I am developing a java application for a inventory management system.i used weblaf lookandfeel for designing.
i added a statusbar and added a button to statusbar named notification and i can see a notification popup menu by
clicking the button.i wrote this code to find min level items,

```
public void low() {

    try {
        ResultSet rs = Database.getConnection().executeQuery("SELECT name FROM detail WHERE qty<=100");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now i need to all the low level items to notification popup,How to do this correctly.Hightly appriciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Popup, which is a Swing UI component should display the list of names. What you are doing here is printing them out on the console. Rewrite the `low` method as follows, to get a list of all the names:

```
public List<String> low() {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ResultSet rs = Database.getConnection().executeQuery("SELECT name FROM detail WHERE qty<=100");
        while (rs.next()) {
            items.add(rs.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return items;
}
```

Then you can fill your popup with the items of the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot.i'll try that :-)

Comment: But how to add this arraylist to popup menu?

Comment: You probably want to have a [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) in your [Popup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: @stackquestions, `yeah.i figured it out .thanks` - then don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark, so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I'm sorry.i forgot it :-)